# Turn my java project into executable file

Tags: java, executable

I made a Java project and I just want to make it into an executable file to get a bounce, I found some answers related in this website with some programs. I tried using the programs but they did not work. PLEASE help me with the most efficient way to turn my Java project which consists of four classes into an executable file.

Comment: An executable file on what platform?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert my Java program to an .exe file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export -> Runnable jar, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

In Java you make an executable .jar file, not an exe. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-make-an-executable-jar-file/) to help with that:

Comment: This is the first time that I make an executable file , the tutorials that were posted looks confusing for me